# ASP.NET Menu control automatically adding inline style

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS 2010 and the ASP.NET Menu control is adding the following inline style:

```
style="float: left;"
```

I added the following to the control's declaration:

```
IncludeStyleBlock="false" CssClass="myClass" style=""
```

without success.  Is there a trick to get this control to NOT add styling?

---

The menu is rendering as such:

```
<div class="myMenu" style="float: left;" >
<ul id="menu" style="float: left ....

</div>
```

The top level div doesn't need to float.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

The `float:left` is what is making the menu items appear side-by-side. Is this not what you want?

If you really want it gone, you can try modifying your css:

```
.myClass { float: none !important; }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add: `.myClass > ul { float: none !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Using inline styles overwrites behaviour of other css defined styles. The solution that I used was jQuery:

```
$("<DIV> id").removeAttr("style");
$("<UL> class").removeAttr("style");
$("<UL> class").find("li").removeAttr("style");
```

Regards!